# SSL Certificates when upgrading Java

Tags: java, jvm, ssl-certificate

I added GitHub's SSL certificate to my Jenkins JVM. If the Java version is updated, will the SSL certificate remain in the keystore or will I have to import it again? I have two folders in the Java folder. One is default and the other is a jdk___ folder. Which folder will be updated, and thus the one I should add the certificate to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have added GitHub certificate in truststore, not keystore.
Truststore is where all the certificates are stored which client can trust on.

In JRE, it is stored in lib/security/cacerts file. So, if this file is getting replaced during upgrade, you need to re-import. You can also try backing up this file and restoring it again, but you will loose any new certs that this new Java provides out of box.